# Meaning of "dying ain't much of a living"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

This is one very catchy phrase from an old movie.

> *Dying ain't much of a living, son*
>
> -Clint Eastwood (The Outlaw Josey Wales)

I know what does it mean literally but when to use it generally in day to day life?

I mean you don't really want to be in such situation. But for fun if you want to use this line, mocking a tough guy from movie.

Comment: Working in a dangerous profession is not a good way to support yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that if your choice of occupation (such as being a highway robber) is going to kill you then maybe you should change occupations.

But understand that it's difficult to envision this line being used in a "fun", mocking way (unlike, say, "Make my day"). It apparently has become the title of a [Bon Jovi song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/jonbonjovi/dyinaintmuchofalivin.html), but that song is kind of a "downer", based my reading of the lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

To the person who posed the question: There are almost no situations where you would use this quote 'in real life', unless you are a professional assassin whose life has been threatened... (It's funny to English speakers because it juxtaposes the opposites 'dying' and 'living' in a double-entendre: dying is literally 'not living' but 'a living' is also shorthand for 'earning a living", the implication being that you can't make a living from an activity that results in your death. You need to consider the previous line also, to which this line was a response - I think it was: "A man's gotta do somethin' for a livin' ..." spoken by the bounty hunter who confronted Josey Wales. The answer referred to above is probably among the best retorts in film history.